# Rails app not recognizing active record entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a rails app and have create a basic and pro plan in database, here is output of Plan.all from rails console:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Plan id: 1, name: "basic", price: #<BigDecimal:7f9aad0bf578,'0.0',9(27)>, created_at: "2016-11-03 04:21:55", updated_at: "2016-11-03 04:21:55">, #<Plan id: 2, name: "pro", price: #<BigDecimal:7f9aad0be448,'0.1E2',9(27)>, created_at: "2016-11-03 04:22:21", updated_at: "2016-11-03 04:22:21">]>
```

When I create a user under either plan i get this error:

> 1 error prohibited this user from being saved: Plan must exist

Not sure why it is not picking up the plans.

Comment: Can you explain how the Plan and User models are associated?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Plan must exist" when you create a user means that whatever plan_id you gave to the user does not match up with the id of an actual plan in the database.  Check the plans you have created, look a their ids, and make sure the plan_id you give to your user matches the id of one of those plans.
Note: it is not enough to create database tables for each of the 2 types of plans, you must create actual instances of the plans.
Also: check to make sure you has_many / belongs_to relationship is set up correctly.